# Can't create new Pods pages

Tags: capabilities, pods-framework

this is strange.

Suddenly I can't create any more Pods pages! In the edit page screen instead of publish the main button shows submit for review and when I push it WP says: You are not allowed to edit this post.

Well, I'm the admin so I shouldn't have any problems, and indeed I created other pages before. The roles and capabilities seems ok to me...

What's going on?

EDIT: Looks like is a problem in a last upgrade in my functions.php code. But I can't get what!

Comment: Please add more info. And check with your host that you didn't exceed any limit. Then go, deactivate all plugins except pods (start with recently activated ones), then switch to the default theme and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: in local the problem doesn't seem to happen

Comment: No it doesn't, code wasn't matched. It looks like is a problem in my function.php code. Can't guess what!

Comment: I found the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

There was a line of code that was deleting all posts as soon they were created.

It may seems slly but it was wanted, I'm building a really custom app based on wordpress...

Simply I forgot that this would cancel many other things that pods saves as post, like pods pages or pods fields.

It's strange hwr that in the page editing screen, the main button was showing "submit for review" instead of "publish", lije wordpress knew about that error in the code. Maybe it decide what to show seeing if it was able to save a draft of the page. Since the drafts were getting deleted all the same, probably it thought I was allowed to publish.

Pretty intricate system!